# Export class and instanciate it immediately on import

Tags: node.js, class, module, require

I have a ES6 class in NodeJS 4 :

vehicule.js

```
"use strict";
class Vehicule {
  constructor(color) {
    this.color = color;
  }
}
module.exports = Vehicule;
```

When I need to instanciate in another file, I find myself doing this :

```
var _Vehicule = require("./vehicule.js");
var Vehicule = new _Vehicule();
```

I'm new to nodeJs, is there a way to do this in one line, or at least in a more readable way ?

Comment: i think it's the right way to do.

Comment: Typically instances go by a lowercase name, so use `import Vehicle from …` and `const vehicle = new Vehicle();`

Comment: Yes, you can do it one line: `var vehicle = new (require("…"))()` but you should ask yourself whether you really want a class when actually you use it as a singleton.

Comment: @Bergi I actually use my class as a singleton factory for DB access (and therefore need a Class so I can have a base factory that I can extend). The "Vehicule" is just an example.
I think I'll go for module.exports = new Vehicule(); as it's readable & singleton unless you tell me it's a bad idea

Comment: No, you do not need a class so that you have a factory that you can extend. Get away from thinking of everything in class terms. A factory is just a function, a singleton is just an object. There is no need for inheritance either.

Comment: @Bergi: The only other way I know is the "Crockford" way (http://www.crockford.com/javascript/inheritance.html) but I think ES6 syntax make it more readable. In my case a factory is rather a "group" of functions providing base SQL functions (run query, selectAll(), ...) that e I like to extends for some sql table

Comment: Then go read http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#designpatternsjavascript

Comment: @Bergi : Thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A class is really supposed to be reused for many objects. So you should require the class itself:

```
var Vehicule = require("./vehicule.js");
```

and then create objects from it:

```
var vehicle1 = new Vehicule('some data here');
var vehicle2 = new Vehicule('other data here');
```

Usually classes start with an upper case letter, and instances of classes (objects themselves) with a lower case one.

If you want a "class" for just one objects, you can just create an inline object:

```
var vehicle = {
    myProperty: 'something'
};

module.exports = vehicle;

//in some other file
var vehicle = require('vehicle');
```

Though if you really, really want to do that in one line, you can do:

```
var vehicle = new (require('vehicle'))('some constructor data here');
```

But that is not recommended. Pretty much ever.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do this in one line:

```
var Vehicule = new (require('./vehicule'))('red');
```

but personally i would prefer two lines for the same reasons mentioned by @ralh.